# AngularJS: How to save the pre-selected radio button when another radio button is clicked for open the relative section

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this case, I have a radio button for open a section called subscription. When clicked the section open with other 2 radio buttons, weekly and monthly. The weekly radio button is pre-selected and should be saved when I press the first radio opening the section and preserved. What I need to achieve here is also that a user can change the subscription to monthly and also this state should be preserved after save. 
So when the user backs or refreshes the page the section subscription remain open with the chosen period. I would like to know the mofiication I have to do in my view and ctrl to reach the goal above mentioned.

The view:

```
<!--|||  Subscribe Start  |||-->
    <div class="main-edit">
        <div class="subsection">
            <div class="flex-container row">
                <div class="radiobutton-group">
                    <div class="width-140">
                        <input id="subscribed" type="checkbox" ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed" value="subscribed" class="radiobutton" ng-click="modifySubscriptionType(type)">
                        <label class="label highlight inline no-bottom-margin" for="subscribed">
                            {{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_subscribe' | translate }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed > 0">
                <div class="flex-container row" ng-show="getUnselectedEngines().length > 0">
                    <div class="input-group flex-1" ng-switch="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription">
                        <label class="label" for="name">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_recurrence' | translate }}</label>
                        <div class="inputs-container-row half-width" name="oftenReportSent">
                            <span class="radiobutton flex-1" ng-class="{'checked' : analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'WeeklyAnalytics'}" name="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="WeeklyAnalytics" 
                                ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription" 
                                ng-checked="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'WeeklyAnalytics'" 
                                value="WeeklyAnalytics"
                                id="WeeklyAnalytics"
                                ng-required="">
                                <label for="WeeklyAnalytics">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_weekly' | translate }}</label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="radiobutton flex-1" ng-class="{'checked' : analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'MonthlyAnalytics'}">
                                <input type="radio" name="MonthlyAnalytics" 
                                ng-model="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription" 
                                ng-checked="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription === 'MonthlyAnalytics'" 
                                value="MonthlyAnalytics" 
                                id="MonthlyAnalytics" 
                                ng-required="">
                                <label for="MonthlyAnalytics">{{ 'user_settings_emailStatistics_monthly' | translate }}</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div> <span style="color:red;" ng-show="analyticsEmailSettings.subscription == null">Please select option</span></div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The CTRL:

```
searchApp.controller('UserSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$rootScope', 'aiStorage', 'userConfig', 'UserSettingsService', 'WebsiteSource', 'AnalyticsEmailService', 'toaster', '$translate', '$timeout', 'ngTableParams',
function($scope, $q, $rootScope, store, userConfig, UserSettingsService, WebsiteSource, AnalyticsEmailService, toaster, $translate, $timeout, ngTableParams) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.availableLanguages = {
            da: 'Dansk',
            en: 'English',
            sv: 'Svensk'
        }

        $scope.userInfo = store.get('user')
        $scope.loadingAction = false
        $scope.selectFlag = false
        $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = []
        $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
        $scope.analyticsEmailSettings = {}
        $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription = 'WeeklyAnalytics'
        $scope.engines = angular.copy(WebsiteSource.sites)

        AnalyticsEmailService.getUserSubscription().then(
            function success(response) {
                $scope.loadingAction = false
                $scope.subscription = response
                console.log('response.data', response.data)
                $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer = populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(response.data)
                $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed = (response.data.length > 0)

            },
            function error() {})

    }

    function populateSubscribedEnginesFromServer(data) {
        var subscriptionEngines = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var subscription = data[i]
            var engine = $scope.engines.filter(function(x) {
                return x.id === subscription.engine
            })[0]
            console.log('engine', engine)
            if (engine) subscription.name = engine.name

            subscriptionEngines.push(subscription)
        }
        console.log('subscriptionEngines', subscriptionEngines)
        return subscriptionEngines
    }

    $scope.save = function() {
            $scope.loadingAction = true
            if ($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEngines.length; i++) {
                    var obj = {
                        'type': $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].type,
                        'engine': $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].id || $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].engine,
                        'title': $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].name,
                        'name': $scope.subscriptionEngines[i].name
                    }
                    $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.push(obj)
                }
                AnalyticsEmailService.updatesubscriptions($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer, function success(response) {}, function error() {})
                $timeout(function() {
                    AnalyticsEmailService.getUserSubscription().then(
                        function success(response) {
                            $scope.loadingAction = false
                            $scope.subscription = response
                            $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscribed = (response.data.length > 0)
                        },
                        function error() {})
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                AnalyticsEmailService.unsubscribe($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription, function success(response) {}, function error() {})
            }
            UserSettingsService.save({
                userId: $scope.userInfo.id
            }, $scope.userInfo, function() {
                $scope.loadingAction = false
                userConfig.setCurrentUserConfig($scope.userInfo)
                userConfig.setUserLocale()
                store.set('user', $scope.userInfo)
                toaster.pop({
                    type: 'success',
                    body: $translate.instant('notifications_user_settings_changed_success')
                })
            }, function() {})
            $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
        }
        // removeSelectedEngines
    $scope.getUnselectedEngines = function() {
        if (!$scope.engines)
            return []

        var unselectedEngines = []
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.engines.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.filter(function(x) {
                    return x.engine === $scope.engines[i].id
                }).length == 0)
                unselectedEngines.push($scope.engines[i])
        }

        // All engines

        return unselectedEngines
    }
    $scope.addEngineToSubscriptionServer = function(engine) {
        if ($scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription) {
            engine.type = $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription;
            $scope.subscriptionEngines.push(engine);
            $scope.save();
            if ($scope.engine !== undefined)
                $scope.engine.current = $scope.getUnselectedEngines()[0];

            $scope.showMessage = true;
            $scope.successMessage = "Subscription saved successfully!!!"
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.showMessage = false;
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            $scope.selectFlag = true
        }
    }

    $scope.removeEngineFromSubscriptionServer = function(engine) {
        var index = $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.indexOf(engine)
        $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.splice(index, 1)
        if ($scope.engine !== undefined)
            $scope.engine.current = $scope.getUnselectedEngines()[0]

        $scope.save()
    }

    $scope.modifySubscriptionType = function(engine) {

        if ($scope.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics')
            return $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription = 'WeeklyAnalytics'

        return $scope.analyticsEmailSettings.subscription
        $scope.save()

    }

    // $scope.modifySubscriptions = function(engine, type, functionality) {
    //     var index = $scope.engines.indexOf(engine)
    //     $scope.engines[index].type = type
    //     if (functionality == 'add') {
    //         $scope.subscriptionEngines = []
    //         engine.type = 'WeeklyAnalytics'
    //         $scope.subscriptionEngines.push(engine)
    //     } else {
    //         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length; i++) {
    //             if ($scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].engine == engine.id) {
    //                 if (functionality == 'update')
    //                     $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer[i].type = type
    //                 else if (functionality == 'remove') {
    //                     $scope.subscriptionEnginesFromServer.splice(i, 1)
    //                 }
    //                 break
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    //     $scope.save()
    // }
}
])
```

ScreenShot:
[The view section of the radio buttons involved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIBNR.png)